# How to read and extract and merge multiple huge size csv(1G~)?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I have multiple huge size csv(1GB~)like below

```
path = 'C:/Users/csvfiles'
```

sample1.csv

```
A B C
0 a A
0 c C
1 d D
```

sample2.csv

```
A B C
1 e E
0 f G
0 g G
```

I would like to get the below df

```
A B C
1 d D
1 e E
```

I would like to extract 1 for columnA.
It may become easy to handle (considering the memory size).

In my opinion, I should use chunksize  and process some extraction and then merge...(to save memory size)

It was very complicated for me.

Can I ask how to read and merge huge size csv ?(and how to save memory)

Comment: sorry,I edited my question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use `glob` to grab files
- use `pd.concat` to put them together
- use `query` to get where column `A` is `1`

***code***

```
pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob('csvs/*')]).query('A == 1')

   A  B  C
2  1  d  D
0  1  e  E
```

***or*** if you want to track where each row came from in the first level of the index.

```
pd.concat(
    {i: pd.read_csv(f) for i, f in enumerate(glob('csvs/*'))}).query('A == 1')

     A  B  C
0 2  1  d  D
1 0  1  e  E
```

Answer (score 0):

the important issue is that modifying data frames is slow.
if you have many files (you'll probably need to experiment), a better approach would be to aggregate the results in a list, and convert to data frame only in the end

```
l = []
while df in generate_df():
    l += df[df.A==1].to_dict('records')
big_df = pandas.DateFrame(l)
```